# Seemingly random error occurring between an AngularJs Service and an MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am currently having an issue where my AngularJs Service is triggering an error while connecting to an MVC Controller.

My code is as follows:

AngularJs Controller function that calls the Service:

```
    $scope.SubmitChangeForm = function () {
        $scope.submitted = true;

        ChangeForm.submitapplication($scope.application,
            function (data) {
                $scope.submissionCompleted = true;
            },
            function (data) {
                $scope.errorOccurred = true;
            }
        );
    };
```

ChangeForm service:

```
angular.module('app')
.service('ChangeForm', function ($http) {
    return {
        submitapplication: function (application, success, error) {
            var data = { "app": application };
            $http.post('/applicant/submitapplication', data).success(success).error(error);
        },

        sendschoolemail: function (serviceId, success, error) {
            var data = { "ServiceId": serviceId };
            $http.post('/email/emailschool', data).success(success).error(error);
        },

        sendstudentemail: function (serviceId, success, error) {
            var data = { "ServiceId": serviceId };
            $http.post('/email/emailstudent', data).success(success).error(error);
        }
    }
});
```

ApplicantController (MVC Controller):

```
    [Route("submitapplication"), System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubmitApplication(Applicant app)
    {
        //ModelState.AddModelError("Test", "Test Error");

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var messages = GetModelMessages(ModelState);

            LogError(messages);

            Response.StatusCode = 500;

            return new JsonResultView("Error occurred", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        try
        {
            app.DateSubmitted = System.DateTime.Now;

            var success = _layer.AddApplicant(app);

            if (success)
            {
                SendEmails(app);
            }
            else
            {
                Response.StatusCode = 500;
                LogError("Error occurred writing to database");

                return new JsonResultView("Error occurred", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

            return new JsonResultView(success, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogError(ex.ToString());

            Response.StatusCode = 500;
            return new JsonResultView("Error occurred", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

The surrounding Try/Catch was to see if the error was occurring at the root of the controller for some reason.

The form works the majority of the time, but sometimes an error is being handled by the AngularJs Controller (triggering the $scope.errorOccurred = true; line) and no errors are being logged by the MVC controller. This would suggest to me that it is trying to call the MVC controller but failing for some reason.

Can anyone see what may be causing the issue? I am relatively new to AngularJS and client side scripting so it may be something very trivial.

One of my colleagues managed to trip the error but nothing appeared in the logs. I asked him to repeat the submission with the exact same form content and this time it worked.

Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Your controller accepts an `app` parameter of type `Applicant`. Are you sending the correct object while making the request? `var data = { "app": application };` I believe it is unable to find your action as it doesn't match the action's signature

Comment: and please verify your `RouteConfig.cs` that your registered route is somewhat like `url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"`

Comment: Hi,thanks for replying. Yes the correct object is being sent, the error only seems to happen at random intervals. The majority of the time it works fine.